# Parsing EMail with VB6 - not splitting properly

Tags: parsing, email, vb6

When I parse through an email that looks like:

included_po~301993959 'VBCRLF

po_no~vendor~part_no~class~type_code~buyer~qty_ordered~measure~balance_on_order~cost~amt_ordered~order_date~delivery_date~ship_Date~receive_date~open~wo_no 'VBCRLF

301993959~100000~88008K~PROBE 800~F~VAX~4.0 ~EA~4.0~100.3300~401.32000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~STOCK 'VBCRLF
301993959~100000~TFCI-010-50~WIRE SPTEF~F~VAX~1.0~SP~1.0~12.6400~12.64000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~STOCK 'VBCRLF
301993959~100000~TFIR-010-50~WIRE SPTEF~F~VAX~1.0~SP~1.0~12.6400~12.64000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~STOCK 'VBCRLF

using code:

```
Public Sub AddItems()

Dim aLineItem() As String
Dim aItem() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iCnt As Double
Dim msg
Dim Item As Items

ReDim sWo(0)
iCnt = 0
For i = 1 To UBound(sMsg())

aLineItem = Split(sMsg(i), vbCrLf)
For j = 1 To UBound(aLineItem)
    If aLineItem(j) <> "" Then
        If blah = 1 Then
            Debug.Print ("...." & aLineItem(j))
        End If
        aItem = Split(aLineItem(j), "~")
        If (aItem(0) <> "") And (aItem(0) <> "included_po") And (aItem(0) <> "po_no") Then
          Item.PO_num = GetWo(aItem(1))
            If Item.PO_num <> "0" Then
                Item.Company = aItem(1)
                Item.Delivery_date = aItem(12)
                Item.pn = aItem(2)
                Item.QTY_ordered = aItem(6)
                Item.Unit_Price = aItem(9)
            End If 'If Item.PO_num <> "0" Then
        End If 'If aItem(1) <> "" Then
    End If ' If aLineItem(j) <> "" Then
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

The email parsing looks like this:

....301993959~100000~88008K~PROBE

....8800~F~VAX~4.0~EA~4.0~100.3300~401.32000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~S

....TOCK

Is there a better way to parse this email?

EDIT #1:

```
Public Sub GetMailMsg()
Dim pop3 As jmail.pop3
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim mailID As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim sSubject As String

j = 0

ReDim sMsg(0)

'connect to the mail box
Set pop3 = New pop3
pop3.Connect "REMOVED FOR SECURITY"


'Get message count
iCount = pop3.Count


'Read Messages
For i = 1 To iCount
 sSubject = pop3.Messages.Item(i).Subject
Label1.Caption = "Reading message.." & sSubject
DoEvents
If InStr(sSubject, "China Purchase Orders") <> 0 Then 'email test
j = j + 1
ReDim Preserve sMsg(j)
sMsg(j) = pop3.Messages.Item(i).Body
Label1.Caption = "Reading mail message for order " & sSubject
If blah = 1 Then
    Debug.Print ("Reading mail message for order " & sSubject)
    Debug.Print ("Reading mail message for order " & sMsg(j))
End If
End If
Next

pop3.Disconnect
Set pop3 = Nothing
End SUb
```

--EDIT #2

OUTPUT FROM DEBUG:
Reading mail message for order China Purchase Orders
Reading mail message for order 
included_po~301993959

po_no~vendor~part_no~class~type_code~buyer~qty_ordered~measure~balance_o 'VBCRLF

n_order~cost~amt_ordered~order_date~delivery_date~ship_Date~receive_date 'VBCRLF

~open~wo_no 'VBCRLF

301993959~100000~88008K~PROBE 'VBCRLF

8800~F~VAX~4.0~EA~4.0~100.3300~401.32000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~S 'VBCRLF

TOCK 'VBCRLF

301993959~100000~TFCI-010-50~WIRE 'VBCRLF

SPTEF~F~VAX~1.0~SP~1.0~12.6400~12.64000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~ST 'VBCRLF

OCK 'VBCRLF

301993959~100000~TFIR-010-50~WIRE 'VBCRLF

SPTEF~F~VAX~1.0~SP~1.0~12.6400~12.64000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~ST 'VBCRLF

OCK 'VBCRLF

Comment: The question is vague...Is it not doing what its supposed to be doing? What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: It's trying to grab (for instance) 011513 to be Item.Delivery_Date. But since the lines are breaking somewhat randomly I can't parse it correctly. "301993959" should always be the start of a line and "STOCK" should be the end. Instead it's broken up into 3 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lines aren't breaking up properly makes me think there is a problem in the line `aLineItem = Split(sMsg(i), vbCrLf)`. Please check whether you don't have any `vbCrLF` in the line you aren't getting right.

Is that line one continuous line?

**Edit #1 @ Jan 16, 2013 1:16pm EST:**

I created a file and pasted provided input.
I created a simple program and incorporated your code into it. Please see produced DEBUG below, consisting as expected with 3 lines beginning with 301993959 and ending with STOCK. This is the correct and desirable output, right?

`....301993959~100000~TFCI-010-50~WIRE SPTEF~F~VAX~1.0~SP~1.0~12.6400~12.64000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~STOCK 
....301993959~100000~TFIR-010-50~WIRE SPTEF~F~VAX~1.0~SP~1.0~12.6400~12.64000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~STOCK
....301993959~100000~88008K~PROBE 800~F~VAX~4.0 ~EA~4.0~100.3300~401.32000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~STOCK`

So the code you provided is working fine. If you say the input file is fine too, that means the issue is with how you are reading that email, specifically how you populate `sMsg()`. Can you post that code please?

**Edit #2 @ Jan 16, 2013 2:32pm EST:**

You are getting some unwanted `vbCrLf`s in your single record line and you can't split it the way you want. Here is what I suggest you do:

1) If you can modify `GetMailMsg` to instead of loading Body as it is, go through line by line to avoid generating unwanted `vbCrLf`s. I have zero experience with pop objects so I don't know if that is possible.

2) If the number of unwanted `cbCrLf`s is consistent, ex: 2 in a single record, then you can simply adjust your code to concatenate split records like this

```
DIM concatLine As String
For j = 1 To UBound(aLineItem) Step 3
    concatLine = aLineItem(j) & aLineItem(j+1) & aLineItem(j+2)
    If concatLine <> "" Then
        If blah = 1 Then
            Debug.Print ("...." & concatLine)
        End If
        aItem = Split(concatLine, "~")
        If (aItem(0) <> "") And (aItem(0) <> "included_po") And (aItem(0) <> "po_no") Then
          Item.PO_num = GetWo(aItem(1))
            If Item.PO_num <> "0" Then
                Item.Company = aItem(1)
                Item.Delivery_date = aItem(12)
                Item.pn = aItem(2)
                Item.QTY_ordered = aItem(6)
                Item.Unit_Price = aItem(9)
            End If 'If Item.PO_num <> "0" Then
        End If 'If aItem(1) <> "" Then
    End If ' If concatLine <> "" Then
Next j
```

3) or better yet, concat string until you reach the end of the record and then split that concatenated string.

```
DIM concatLine As String
DIM detailsRecord as Integer

For detailsRecord  = 1 To UBound(aLineItem)
    if LCase(Right(aLineItem(detailsRecord),5)) = 'wo_no' Then Exit For ' when we find this tag, we know where details record begin
Next detailsRecord 
For j = detailsRecord + 1 To UBound(aLineItem) ' begin looping detail records
    concatLine = concatLine + aLineItem(j)

    If UCase(Right(aLineItem(j), 5)) = "STOCK" Then ' this is your end of the record indicator
        If blah = 1 Then
            Debug.Print ("...." & concatLine)
        End If
        aItem = Split(concatLine, "~")
        If (aItem(0) <> "") Then
          Item.PO_num = GetWo(aItem(1))
            If Item.PO_num <> "0" Then
                Item.Company = aItem(1)
                Item.Delivery_date = aItem(12)
                Item.pn = aItem(2)
                Item.QTY_ordered = aItem(6)
                Item.Unit_Price = aItem(9)
            End If 'If Item.PO_num <> "0" Then
        End If 'If aItem(1) <> "" Then
    End If ' If concatLine <> "" Then
    concatLine = ""
Next j
```

For cases 2 and 3, don't forget to handle the headers first- you will have to move             `If (aItem(0) <> "") And (aItem(0) <> "included_po") And (aItem(0) <> "po_no")` outside the main loop to handle header records (i believe the first 2 or records are headers).

**EDIT #3:** 
I fixed scenario #3 to skip through the header records (assuming 'wo_no' is an indicator of the end of that record), then to concatenate strings to form a single record by searching for an end tag ("STOCK"). This method is going to be flexible enough to handle dynamic number of `vbCrLf`s in the email body that splits a single record into unpredictable number of strings.

The code was typed in the browser, so I don't guarantee it will work :)

Comment: I'll edit the above to show where the lines are breaking in the email... I put in 'VBCRLF to show the actual lines breaks

Comment: I assume the debug line `....8800~F~VAX~4.0~EA~4.0~100.3300~401.32000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~S` should of been `....800~F~VAX~4.0~EA~4.0~100.3300~401.32000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~S`

Still, everything points to extra `VBCRLF`'s inside the what you expect to be a single line. How do you open the email to see the next line characters? Did you try opening it in a hex editor to check CR and LF codes (0D and 0A in hex, 13 and 10 in decimal)?

Comment: In the Hex Editor.. The OD OA are showing up exactly where they are supposed to be showing up.

Comment: Whats the result of `Debug.Print ("Reading mail message for order " & sMsg(j)` after going through the email?

Comment: Reading mail message for order China Purchase Orders
Reading mail message for order 
included_po~301993959

po_no~vendor~part_no~class~type_code~buyer~qty_ordered~measure~balance_o
n_order~cost~amt_ordered~order_date~delivery_date~ship_Date~receive_date
~open~wo_no

301993959~100000~88008K~PROBE
8800~F~VAX~4.0~EA~4.0~100.3300~401.32000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~S
TOCK
301993959~100000~TFCI-010-50~WIRE
SPTEF~F~VAX~1.0~SP~1.0~12.6400~12.64000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~ST
OCK
301993959~100000~TFIR-010-50~WIRE
SPTEF~F~VAX~1.0~SP~1.0~12.6400~12.64000~011513~012313~012313~000000~Y~ST
OCK

Comment: Could you please put `VBCRLF`s in where they appear from that email? I think i see a VBCRLF in `S TOCK` and then `ST OCK`

Comment: I had a miserable time trying to format- see EDIT #2. It's almost as if there is a character limit of about 72.

Comment: I know what you mean, it would be nice for SO to develop some kind of feature to post files or file data.
Anyway, could you please indicate where all the `vbCRLF`s are in the edit 2?

Comment: So there is your problem... you have `vbCrLf`s in what you wanted to be a single line. That's why you get a split in wrong places. Can you fix those unwanted `vbCrLf`'s from the email body?

Comment: those vbCRLFs are not actually in the body. This is just how it gets parsed. I've been reading up and it may just be a pop3 standard: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt

Comment: They may not be in the body, but they are in the array that you are splitting. That is the problem.

Comment: I'll try to figure it out. If I find the solution I will post. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22856/discussion-between-tree-and-george)

Comment: OK Ended up doing a version of what Edit #3 looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what should start each line, then use the Split function using "301993959".

```
Dim LineItems(100) As String
x = Split(sMsg(i), "301993959")
For j = 1 To UBound(x) - 1 'Don't use 0 becuase you don't need that part
      LineItems(j - 1) = x(j)
Next i
```

Of Course you could take it one step further by then splitting each item in the string using "~" as your second delimiter.

```
Dim LineItems(100, 15) As String
x = Split(Text1.Text, "301993959")
For j = 1 To UBound(x) - 1 'Don't use 0 becuase you don't need that part
  y = Split(x(j), "~")
  For k = 1 To 15
    LineItems(j - 1, k) = y(k)
  Next k
Next j
```